# Which credentials should I put in for Google App Engine BulkLoader at JAVA development server?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bulkloader

I can't upload data to my GAE Java dev serwer. Bulkloader asks for a password, but no password matches:

```
    D:\python_google_appengine>appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=templates.csv --url=http://localhost:8080/remote_api --kind=EmailMessageTemplate  --application=myappid --insecure
Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20110927.084025
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20110927.084025.sql3
Please enter login credentials for localhost
Email: m@gmail.com
Password for m@gmail.com:
[INFO    ] Connecting to localhost:8080/remote_api
2011-09-27 08:40:44,062 WARNING appengine_rpc.py:435 ssl module not found.
Without the ssl module, the identity of the remote host cannot be verified, and
connections may NOT be secure. To fix this, please install the ssl module from
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl .
To learn more, see http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#rpcssl .
Please enter login credentials for localhost
Email: Interrupted.
```

Then how to create credentials *with a password* on **Java dev server** or bypass password requirement?

I've read answers from here [Which credentials should I put in for Google App Engine BulkLoader at development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260835/which-credentials-should-i-put-in-for-google-app-engine-bulkloader-at-development#2195685) and comments for this issue http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2440 **but it is all about Python dev server not Java**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is temporary issue. Try redeploying application, and restart all the stuff. Use any email and empty password.

Answer (score 0):

For development server of GAE

(1) use browser to goto http://localhost:8080/_ah/login in order check admin email.  The default is test@example.com

(2) add **--email=test@example.com --passin** to the appcfg.py parameters and just press enter for the password prompt

(3) the application id has the prefix of *dev~* for development server e.g.  **application=dev~myappid**